# Function pointers in higher-order functions in x86-64

Tags: segmentation-fault, x86-64, function-pointers, higher-order-functions

The `reduce` function which I want to write in x68-64 may have this functionality:

```
unsigned reduce( unsigned (*fnct_ptr) (unsigned param_one, unsigned param_two),
                    unsigned init,
                    size_t len,
                    const unsigned arr[]){
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            init = fnct_ptr(init, arr[i]);
    }
    return init;
}
```

The higher-order function takes a pointer to a two parameter function, an initial value, an array and a counter for its length.

My current attempt looks as follows:

```
reduce:   

    XOR rbx, rbx    ; set counter to zero
    MOV rsp, rdi    ; fnctPntr -> rsp  
    MOV rax, rsi    ; init -> rax  
    
while:
    CMP rbx, rdx    ; if counter >= lengrh -> end 
    JGE  end
        
        MOV  rdi, rax          ; load parameters to rdi and rsi
        MOV  rsi, [rcx+rbx*8]  
        CALL rsp               ; call function with pointer 
        INC  rbx
        JMP  while
end:        
    RET
```

The higher order function **and** the function as parameter may follow the [calling convention](https://wiki.osdev.org/System_V_ABI#x86-64) So the parameters have to be put into `rdi` and `rsi` before every call of the function and receive the result in `rax`.
I'm getting segmentation faults at the call if the function. Probably because of a wrong address size, since the value is 32-Bit but dealing with 64-Bit Register.

Comment: `rsp` is the stack pointer!  Don't overwrite it with data.  `call` pushes are return address to `[rsp-=8]`.  Also, RBX is call-preserved, that's why you can use it as a loop counter that will survive across calls.  But you aren't saving/restoring your caller's value of it.  Also, RCX and RDX are call-clobbered, so you'll need different registers for those in your loop.

Comment: Look at compiler-generated asm for your C function for an example of how to get this right, including stack alignment which will happen for free with pushing an odd number of call-preserved registers.  [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)